# is there any way to "logout with all devices" from dropbox API v2

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api, dropbox-sdk-js

I am using Dropbox API v2. User of my app wants to logout from Dropbox with all his devices. I think this is equivalent to revoke all access tokens for my app.

I know how to revoke a known access token (and my app provides a logout which does this).
I also know that the user can unlink my app from his dropbox on the dropbox website (but this is a bit cumbersome).

For convenience, I would like to add a feature allowing him to do this from my app.

Another reason is, that processing of the callback-URL may fail. Then the generated access token remains valid, even if it is never used.

As Dropbox access tokens never expire, users might feel bad if there are unknown or unused access tokens flying around.

Answer (score 1):

No, the Dropbox API doesn't offer a way to programmatically unlink/revoke all access tokens for an app. We'll consider this a feature request.

Answer (score -1):

I used to redirect to logout page, which invalidate the token as well as "ask for permissions" for app on the next login ... it is not aesthetic, but worked.

```
if (this.isAuth()) {
    this.authToken = '';
    window.open('https://www.dropbox.com/logout', '_blank');
}
```

Comment: Peter, it is not necessary to go to the logout page. You can revoke the token via the API. The problem is, that if by whatever reason, you loose the token, you can no longer revoke it and it remains valid until the user unlinks from the app. I do not want to drive users away from my app.

Comment: Btw. Logging out does not revoke access tokens